# Maximum and minimum values of $f(x)=\frac{\cos x- \sin x}{\cos x+\sin x}, x\geq0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry, inequality, maxima-minima

Find the Maximum and minimum values of $f(x)=\frac{\cos x- \sin x}{\cos x+\sin x}, x\geq0 $ tanx$ \neq -1$

I've tried to find the derivative:
$$ f'(x)= \frac{-(\cos x+\sin x)(\sin x+\cos x)-(\cos x-\sin x)^2}{(\cos x+\sin x)^2}$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{-2}{  (\cos x+\sin x)^2  }$$

$f'(x)<0$ as tan x $\neq$ -1

$x\geq 0 \Rightarrow f(x)<f(0)$

$f(x)<1$.

So maximum value is 1. Is this correct? What is the minimum value?

Comment: @Leonhard Euler Please answer the question.

Comment: The range of this function is from $-\infty$ to $\infty$

Comment: This is somewhat hard to read. But assuming you've calculated the derivative correctly, you'd like to know: Where are the critical points? And remember, critical points have to be in the domain of your function!

Comment: You are correct that $f'(x)$ is strictly negative ... when $f'(x)$ is defined. However, notice that the denominator of $f'$ can be zero, so the derivative can be $-\infty$. For more insight, you should draw a picture of $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Divide by $\cos x$.

$$\dfrac{\cos x-\sin x}{\cos x+\sin x}$$
$$=\dfrac{1-\tan x}{1+\tan x}$$
$$=\dfrac{\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)-\tan x}{1+\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)\cdot\tan x}$$
$$=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)$$

Therefore the range of this function extends from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.

Comment: Now that's nice, +1.

Answer (score 3):

I would try it another way:

$$
\cos(x)-\sin(x) = \sqrt{2}\cos(x+\frac{\pi}{4}) \\
\cos(x)+\sin(x) = \sqrt{2}\cos(x-\frac{\pi}{4})
$$

then

$$
f(x)=\frac{\cos(x+\frac{\pi}{4})}{\cos(x-\frac{\pi}{4})}=-\frac{\sin(x-\frac \pi 4)}{\cos(x-\frac \pi 4)}=-\tan(x-\pi/4) \\
$$

As you might know, the function $\tan(x)$ is not bounded. Hence your $f(x)$ has no global maxima or minima. E.g. it takes all values from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.